# The user `ldl` is exists in the root group, but when I use `groups root` check it, do not shows the `ldl` user

Tags: linux, users, group

The user `ldl` is exists in the root group, but when I use `groups root` check it, do not shows the `ldl` user.

```
[root@localhost Qiyun02]# usermod -g root ldl
[root@localhost Qiyun02]# groups root
root : root
```

You see, use `groups root` list the user, do not shows the `ldl`.

---

**EDIT**

I also tried :

```
usermod -a -G root ldl
```

append the user `ldl` to `root` group, but still use `groups root` do not shows the `ldl` user.

Comment: Do you notice that you’re querying two different users?

Comment: In addition to what @JeffSchaller said, you have to log out and back in to see the effect.

Comment: what does `getent group root` say?   BTW, you're using `groups` wrong.  `groups USERNAME` shows what groups USERNAME is in.  i.e. it is not `groups GROUPNAME`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `groups` command is not for displaying the members of a group.  Rather it's for displaying the groups that a user is a member of.

So `groups root` will show you all the groups that the root user is a member of.

If you have `members` installed, you can use `members root` to show you all the users that are in the `root` group.

Otherwise, you can just use `getent group root` to see all the users that are in the `root` group.

Edited to show `getent` example, because as @cas pointed out, the local group file is not the only source of group information, especially on a networked machine that may be part of an AD domain, or a NIS+ domain, or which may simply be using an alternate authentication database, like ldap, or mysql, or another tool like `extrausers` (again, thanks to @cas).

Comment: use `getent` rather than `grep ... /etc/group`.  the /etc/group file is NOT the only possible  source of group data, just as /etc/passwd is not the only possible source of user data.

Comment: very good point, @cas

Comment: that's worth a +1 now.   btw, not only useful on networked machines - e.g. there's dozens of NSS modules (e.g. for berkeley db, pgsql, mysql, ldap, and more. There's one called 'extrausers' which I've used several times, allows you to have additional passwd, group, and shadow files).

Comment: thank you, @cas.  I appreciate your contribution to this answer.  I'd never heard of `extrausers`, but I can see many ways it would be useful.

Comment: i once used extrausers to give static uids and gids to users from an AD domain (not administered by me) where the admins refused to install the unix extensions.  I wrote a perl script, run from cron, to recursively query the AD server to build up a list of users and groups (the recursion was needed here because groups can be members of other groups in AD. in unix, only users can be members of groups).  Auth was still done via AD but uid, gid, shell, home dir, etc came from the extrausers files.  This also sped up `ls -l` etc because it avoided the need for AD lookups for every uid/gid.

Comment: @cas thanks.  that sounds very interesting, and it might be able to help me out in my own work, where we see similar issues.  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Kennedy reminder, the `groups` do not shows a group's all members.

You can also use the `id` to check a user's groups, I use `root` as example:

```
$ id root
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) group=0(root)
```